# How do I get the domain from an OGRSpatialReference?

Tags: gdal, ogr, c++

I would like to know what the projected bounds are for a spatial reference using OGRSpatialReference.  Is there some way to use the GetProjParm method to get this information?

An example of what I'm looking for can be seen as the "projected bounds" and "wgs84 bounds" on the following spatialreference.org page:

http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3786/

Comment: I have the same problem although I'm working with the C# port. I don't think it is possible without a large table: I don't think the extents can be calculated from the other parameters. I would love to be proved wrong though. I think I'm going to have to calculate the extents of all my shapes first, which will be cumbersome.